# Can you generate a CSV file from a HTML Table, and simultaneously upload that CSV file to an input type = "file" field. Without prompting a download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically i have an interactive table below setup on my website which i would like to be able to generate a CSV file from the table on a button click, and have simultaneously upload that CSV file to an input type = "file" field. Without prompting a download on the browser.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There should be better ways to get data from a table than converting it to CSV and uploading with a file type input. Could you create the CSV on your backend and instead use http requests to transmit the data?

Comment: The upload field requires the file to be a CSV as its an external service which produces a print read PDF file based on the inputs on the table.

And this is what the user would see also, so id like it to be dynamic.